# Visual Studio Code - default terminal

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm working with VS Code 1.78.2.
I'm working with Angular.
When I open the terminal (top menu->terminal->new terminal) and execute the commane >ng serve I get the error message "Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace."
This used to work fine.
I know there is a solution to point to the project and right click "Open in integrated terminal" but I want it to work through the top menu.
A bad terminal opens as "cmd" and a good terminal opens as "node" I've seen a few tickets here regarding the issue but could not implement any solution.

Comment: Check the folder where you're executing the `ng serve`, see that should be the same folder the file  package.json is

Comment: if you want to set up default terminal, you can do it by click on the 'down arrow' next to the list of terminals, and click on 'select Default Profile'

Comment: I clicked the down arrow but there is no "node" option there. I tried all the profiles available there and nothing helps.

Comment: Eliseo - o.k. you are right. The terminal opens at "C:\study\new-learning\angular\rentalcar>" and it should open at "C:\study\new-learning\angular\rentalcar\RentalCar>" (twice rentalcar). 1) Can I change the directory the cmd opens at? 2) I'm working on a few projects so I need this directory to be project dependant.

Comment: Found it. I had two directories one bellow the other. I should have "file->open folder" the lower one. Eliseo - thanks, your comment helped me find this.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had two directories one bellow the other. I should have "file->open folder" the lower one. Eliseo - thanks, your comment helped me find this.